# Python requests post received a wrong redirect URL

Tags: python, post, cookies, python-requests

I'm trying to log in the web of our dean. But I received an error when posting data via Python Requests. After checking the process with Chrome, I found that the Method `POST` received an URL different from the one received on Chrome.

Here are parts of my codes.

```
import requests
url_get = 'http://ssfw.xjtu.edu.cn/index.portal'
url_post = 'https://cas.xjtu.edu.cn/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fssfw.xjtu.edu.cn%2Findex.portal'

s = requests.session()
user = {"username": email,
        "password": password,
       }

header = {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language':'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length':'141',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host':'cas.xjtu.edu.cn',
    'Origin':'https://cas.xjtu.edu.cn',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36'
    }
```

I got the cookies from via `a = s.get(url_get)` and it should redirect to `url_post`, then add the cookie and referer.

```
_cookie = a.cookies['JSESSIONID']
header['Cookie'] = 'JSESSIONID='+_cookie
header['Referer']= 'https://cas.xjtu.edu.cn/login;jsessionid='+_cookie+'?service=http%3A%2F%2Fssfw.xjtu.edu.cn%2Findex.portal'
r = s.post(url2, json = user, allow_redirects = False)
```

But the `r.headers['location'] == 'https://cas.xjtu.edu.cn/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fssfw.xjtu.edu.cn%2Findex.portal'`

On Chrome it should be `http://ssfw.xjtu.edu.cn/index.portal?ticket=ST-211860-UEh41PdZXfpg4rsvyDg1-gdscas01`

Hmm...Actually I wonder why they are different and how can I jump into the correct URL via `Python Requests` (Seems that the one on Chrome is correct)

Comment: this sounds like you were redirected based on the browser you are using. You don't actually ask any questions here just state information about what happened, do you want to know why it is is different? How to simulate one to act like the other for easier debugging?  What do you actually want to know?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yep...Have already edited. As I can easily log in on Chrome but fail on Python, i wonder why and what happened

Comment: same problem here. it's been so long, they still haven't fixed it.